# Unable to print/view the log (google sheet)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am debugging a script for google sheet and I am trying to print to log as follow:

Logger.log("some txt");

When I do "View -> Log" there is no log ("No functions have been run in this editor session."). This is old code and it used to write to that log no problem. On the other hand, I can see the log if I go "View -> Stackdrive logging". It looks like the log is redirected to this stackfrive logging instead of the normal log.

How do I see the log in the normal log, that is "View -> Log".

Thanks.

Comment: How do you run the function?

Comment: Could you post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends where the function is running.

If you are doing "View -> Log" then it will only show what you ran within the current environment, ie if you clicked on the run function button. But if your function is triggered in the Document, Spreadsheet, or other, then it will not be displayed. So the "View --> Log" is limited.

Stackdriver-Logging on the other hand, logs all the activity from all the environments.